# Android app - google in-app purchase implementation

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

Developing an application (android) for a band. The application is freely available in play store and in every month they will add new album ( movie ) to the application. Also user can view the requested video with in that app ( via streaming from vimeo pro, youtube pro etc ).

But need to restrict only paid / purchased user can view the corresponding video. There is an user table in our DB for saving "which user bought which album", they can view purchased album anytime, multiple times.

Come to my question we have to implement in-app purchase for buying each album. Is it possible ? 
ie if the user liked one album, the process will be

```
Choose the album  ->    purchase via in-app store ( single album, not the entire )   ->
If payment received, then save the user-video details in db   -> user can view that movie in device
```

Is this can be done in android app ?
Or any alternative way available ?

Please advise
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

- you have to create number of `product_id` for number of `album`.and rest of the flow will same.
- For testing,you can make testing account and if you don't wish to create testing account,you can use `android.test.purchased` id for testing
- Sample application of `in-app v3` is already provided with your android-sdk,please look at [Download the Sample Application](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html#GetSample) for reference

Have a look at [In-app Billing Version 3](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html), [Testing In-app Billing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html) for reference

I hope it will be helpful !!

Comment: yes,obviously you can.because your `album` will be uniquely identified by its `product_id`.so you can track who have purchased which album

Comment: ok thanks ... I will try this ... any sand box account available for testing / developing ?

Comment: @ramesh:I've updated my answer regarding your doubt of testing.I hope it will be helpful to you.

Comment: oh thank you sir!!!! one more thing I am new to this can you have any tutorial or sample for in-app purchase ?